# Invoke Delegate From A Thread Instantiated Object

Tags: .net, vb.net

Does anyone know how to invoke a function on the main Form page from an instantiated class that runs in a thread?

```
Public Class Test
    Public Sub Temp()
        Try
            'Operations here
        Catch ex as Exception
            Form1.Invoke(New Form1.LogMessageDelegate(AddressOf frmIP.LogMessage), "Error Message To Be Outputted to TextBox on Main Form")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would have it return a string in a function, but I only invoke the textbox message if there is an exception.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your test class should raise an event that form1 subscribes to. Then create the delegate from there.

Comment: That is not going to work, "Form1" does not produce the proper object reference.  You need a real object reference, use Application.OpenForms(0) if you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Test
 Public Event ErrorMessage(errStr As String)
 Public Sub Temp()
    Try
        'Operations here
    Catch ex as Exception
        RaisEvent ErrorMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
 End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub form1_load() Handles Me.Load
    Dim trd As New Thread(AddressOf RunTestClass)
    trd.Start()
  Ens Sub

  Private Sub RunTestClass()
    Dim _test As New Test
    Addhandler _test.ErrorMessage, AddressOf Test_ErrorMessage
    _test.Temp()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Test_ErrorMessage(errStr As String)
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
              'run code here for UI thread
              End Sub)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I wish I could better understand why that works, but all I can say is, IT WORKS! Thanks so much!